# sending vector files to manufacturers

Tags: vector

Im not at all up with graphic design however i'm trying to get some samples of products manufactured in China and the company has asked for a vector file. I have no idea what it is or how to turn the image I have into a vector file. Any advice at all would be hugely appreciated.

cheers

Casey

Answer (score 1):

First see here:
[What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)

Then see here: [How to create vector graphics In Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop)

Then here: [Convert a line drawing from raster to vector **LINES**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60107/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector-lines) or here: [Convert a line drawing from raster to vector](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector) or here: [How can I convert my raster design to vector for print?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37964/how-can-i-convert-my-raster-design-to-vector-for-print)

Much of any conversion from a raster image to a vector image is dependent upon the image itself. Not all images can be created or converted to vector format without some alteration. And in some cases any vector conversion or creation *may* require a higher level of familiarity with the vector applications.